# How to change axis range displayed in a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a histogram of my df with about 60 thousand of values. After I used        `plt.hist(x, bins = 30)` it gave me something like [image]

The problem is that there are more values bigger than 20 but the frequencies of those values may be smaller than 10. So how can I adjust the axis displayed to show more bins since I want to look at the whole distribution here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with histograms that skew so much towards one value is you're going to essentially flatten out any outlying values. A solution might be just to present the data with two charts.

Can you create another histogram containing only the values greater than 20?

(psuedo-code, since I don't know your data structure from your post)

```
plt.hist(x[x.column > 20], bins = 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it could look like this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values1 = np.random.rand(1000,1)*100
values2 = np.random.rand(100000,1)*5
values3 = np.random.rand(10000,1)*20

values = np.vstack((values1,values2,values3))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.hist(values,bins=30)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_title('with log scale')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.hist(values,bins=30)
ax2.set_title('no log scale')

fig.savefig('test.jpg')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `plt.xscale('log')`

[PyPlot Logarithmic and other nonlinear axis](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#logarithmic-and-other-nonlinear-axis)